# Flutter Listview.builder is duplicating items whose data come from firebase only when i poppin from some other screen otherwise its work fine

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore, flutter-layout, flutter-widget

I am trying to get the data from firebase and then showing in a widget using litview.builder everything seems good but wheneve i returned back to my screen having listview.builder using Navigator.pop then listview.builder duplicating some of the values i check the whole code again and again but didnt found any bug there can u please tell me guys is this a bug or i forget to dispose any parameter there here is the code.;

```
   import 'package:base_flutter_project/core/constants/colors.dart';
import 'package:base_flutter_project/core/constants/length.dart';
import 'package:base_flutter_project/core/constants/text-styles.dart';
import 'package:base_flutter_project/core/viewmodels/customer-payment-view-model.dart';
import 'package:base_flutter_project/ui/custom_widgets/custom-app-bar.dart';
import 'package:base_flutter_project/ui/custom_widgets/custom-bottom-navigation-bar.dart';
import 'package:base_flutter_project/ui/custom_widgets/customer-record-item.dart';
import 'package:base_flutter_project/ui/custom_widgets/customer_record.dart';
import 'package:base_flutter_project/ui/custom_widgets/custom_button_all_screens.dart';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';

class CustomerPaymentListScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _CustomerPaymentListScreenState createState() =>
      _CustomerPaymentListScreenState();
}

class _CustomerPaymentListScreenState extends State<CustomerPaymentListScreen> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    Provider.of<CustomerPayViewModel>(context, listen: false)
        .getCustomerRecords();
    // final model = Provider.of<CustomerPayViewModel>(context, listen: false);
    //  model.getCustomerRecords();
  }
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Consumer<CustomerPayViewModel>(
      builder: (context, model, child) {
        return SafeArea(
          child: Scaffold(
            backgroundColor: backgroundColor,

            bottomNavigationBar: CustomBottomNavigationBar(
              ontap: () {
                Navigator.pushNamed(context, 'dashboard');
              },
            ),

            ///
            ///custom [appbar]
            ///
            appBar: CustomAppBar(
              child: Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                children: <Widget>[
                  Row(
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Text(
                        "Saud ",
                        style: bodyTextStyle,
                      ),
                      IconButton(
                        icon: Icon(
                          Icons.keyboard_arrow_down,
                          size: downArrowSize,
                        ),
                        onPressed: () {},
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                  Text(
                    "Khata",
                    style: subHeadingTextStyle.copyWith(color: greenColor),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),

            ///
            ///body of the screen
            ///
            body: SingleChildScrollView(
              physics: BouncingScrollPhysics(),
              child: Container(
                color: backgroundColor,
                child: Column(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Column(
                      children: <Widget>[
                        SizedBox(height: 6.0),

                        ///
                        ///The first two widget in a row
                        ///
                        getAndGiveCard(),
                        SizedBox(height: 6.0),

                        ///
                        ///Report tag in acolumn
                        ///
                        reportTagCard(),
                        SizedBox(height: 6.0),

                        ///
                        /// Circular Add Subtract Buttons
                        ///
                        circularButtonsRow(),
                        SizedBox(height: 6.0),

                        ///
                        ///here is the listview builder for adding customers paymment record
                        ///
                        // model.isCustomerReady
                        //     ?
                        customerPaymentList(model)
                        // : CircularProgressIndicator(),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),

            ///
            ///Floating action button for adding new customer
            ///
            floatingActionButton: Container(
              alignment: Alignment.bottomRight,
              child: CustomButtonForAllScreens(
                  height: greenButtonHeight,
                  color: greenColor,
                  buttonChild: FlatButton(
                      onPressed: () => Navigator.pushNamed(
                            context,
                            'add_new_customer', /*arguments: model*/
                          ),
                      child: Text('Add new customer',
                          style: greenButtonTextStyle))),
            ),
          ),
        );
      },
    );
  }
}

getAndGiveCard() {
  return Row(
    children: <Widget>[
      Expanded(
        child: CustomerRecord(
          height: customerRecordListHeight,
          listChild: customerRecordData(
            title: 'Rs. 100',
            subTitle: 'You will get',
            textStyle: greenTextStyle,
          ),
        ),
      ),
      SizedBox(
        width: 6.0,
      ),
      Expanded(
        child: CustomerRecord(
          height: customerRecordListHeight,
          listChild: customerRecordData(
            title: 'Rs. 50',
            subTitle: 'You will give',
            textStyle: redTextStyle,
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ],
  );
}

reportTagCard() {
  return CustomerRecord(
      height: customerRecordListHeight,
      listChild: Row(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        children: <Widget>[
          Text(
            'Report',
            style: blackTextStyle,
          ),
          Icon(
            Icons.arrow_forward_ios,
            size: 13.0,
          )
        ],
      ));
}

circularButtonsRow() {
  return Row(
    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
    children: <Widget>[
      Expanded(
        child: Row(
          children: <Widget>[
            Expanded(
                child: FlatButton(
                    onPressed: () {},
                    child: AddSubCustomers(
                        circleChild: Text(
                      'ALL',
                      style: TextStyle(
                          fontSize: 13.0, fontWeight: FontWeight.w500),
                    )))),
            Expanded(
                child: FlatButton(
                    onPressed: () {},
                    child: AddSubCustomers(
                        circleChild: Image.asset('images/minus.png')))),
            Expanded(
                child: FlatButton(
                    onPressed: () {},
                    child: AddSubCustomers(
                        circleChild: Image.asset('images/plus.png')))),
            Expanded(
                child: FlatButton(
                    onPressed: () {},
                    child: AddSubCustomers(
                      circleChild: Text(
                        '0',
                        style: TextStyle(
                            fontSize: 19.0, fontWeight: FontWeight.w500),
                      ),
                    ))),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      FlatButton(
          onPressed: () {},
          child: Image.asset(
            'images/wifi.png',
            width: 19.5,
            height: 13.0,
          )),
    ],
  );
}

customerPaymentList(CustomerPayViewModel model) {
  return Container(
    // padding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom:72.0),
    height: 300,
    color: backgroundColor,
    child: ListView.builder(
        physics: BouncingScrollPhysics(),
        itemCount: model.customerList.length,
        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
          return CustomerRecordItem(
            //once successfully done then migrate it to Haroon bhai method just pass the object to the item
            customer: model.customerList[index],

            ///here i will passed the arguments to a named navigator
            ontap: () {
              Navigator.pushNamed(context, 'customer_payment',
                  arguments: model.customerList[index]);
            },
          );
        }),
  );
}

class AddSubCustomers extends StatelessWidget {
  final circleChild;
  AddSubCustomers({this.circleChild});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      width: 38.0,
      height: 38.0,
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20.0), color: Colors.white),
      child: Center(child: circleChild),
    );
  }
}

customerRecordData({title, subTitle, textStyle}) {
  return Row(
    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
    children: <Widget>[
      Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        children: <Widget>[
          Text(
            title,
            style: textStyle,
          ),
          Text(subTitle, style: customerListSubtitleTextStyle),
        ],
      )
    ],
  );
}
```

Comment: You may find help here: https://firebase.google.com/support/troubleshooter/contact

Comment: maybe add a key to your Items in ListView https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kn0EOS-ZiIc